# Grep command to list the files not owned by a user

Tags: grep, command

Using the grep command display, all files not owned by you in your home directory?

Comment: Probably you rather want to use `find`. I suggest you have a look at the `man` page.

Comment: is that possible with grep? i am not that good , i tried but didn't get any!

Comment: `stat --format="%n:%F:%U" ~/* ~/.??* | grep -v ':username$'` where _username_ is your login id. Play with the `stat` options and possibly pipe through `sed` and/or `awk` for cleaner/fancier output.

Answer (score 6):

`grep` is not the best tool for this job.  Use `find` instead.  For example, `find` combined with the `id -u` command (which outputs your numeric uid):

```
find ~/ ! -uid "$(id -u)"
```

That displays all files in your home directory (and all subdirectories) which are not owned by you.

If you want to restrict it to just your home directory (no subdirectories):

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 ! -uid "$(id -u)"
```

if you want more details on the files:

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 ! -uid "$(id -u)" -ls
```

or

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 ! -uid "$(id -u)" -exec ls -ld {} +
```

(the `-d` option is used here with `ls` to prevent it from displaying the contents of any subdirectories that aren't owned by you)